# send email verification email for asp .net mvc empty project

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, http

Im doing a web Project using asp .net mvc empty template in visual studio 2015.
Im using angular js for the front end of the project. I want to send verification email in the register page when user tries to register himself. 
Thare are lots of examples how to send emails using asp .net mvc template, using allready generated classes and code.
but I want to write code myself and send verification email with verification link.

Comment: Good. then write it please.

Comment: Show us what you've tried for now, include every details if something went wrong by editing your question.